# Spring Rest Controller @RequestBody for an interface except a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am using spring boot rest controller with POST request method, having url (/add) to persist a JSON object, **BUT** inside the RequestBody it accepts **interface** except a **class**.

**Method in Controller:** (IVehicle is an **interface**)

```
@CrossOrigin 
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ResponseEntity<IVehicle> addVehicle(@RequestBody IVehicle vehicle) {

    vehicleService.addVehicle(vehicle); 
    return new ResponseEntity<IVehicle>(vehicleHttpStatus.CREATED); 

}
```

Note: **IVehicle** is an interface.

**JSON Object** being passed VIA AngularJS:

```
$http({

    method : 'POST',
    url : '../localhost/vehicle/add',
    data : $scope.vehicle,
    dataType : 'json',
    headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log( response );

    }, function(error) {
        console.log( error );

});
```

> **ERROR** [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of com.matrix.domain.ui.IVehicle: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.matrix.domain.ui.IVehicle: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5c46d800; line: 1, column: 1]

Please guide me through How do I access the JSON object $scope.vehicle as an Interface in the Rest Controller, I'll be thankful to you.

Thanks

Comment: @pvpkiran That question is different, That is using an interface as Parent, but I'm using interface to accept as parameter...

Answer (score 4):

Assume your **IVehicle** interface is can be represented by a class, say, the class has all but nothing more that **IVehicle** interface's atrributes. Let call it **MyVehicle**

Add the following thing to your interface:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = MyVehicle.class)
public interface IVehicle
```

Comment: @BadshahTracker @JsonDeserialize(as = MyVehicle.class) will try to cast the IVehicle interface to MyVehicle class and deserialize it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Just tomorrow and let you know whether it works fine.

Comment: @KhaNguyễn - And if I have multiple implementations of the interface and I want to select it through any other param. How can we do that?

Comment: @Vikash You could use JsonSubTypes and JsonSubTypes to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assume we have many implementation of an interface.
Lets say `IVehicle` have implementation `CarVehicle` and `BikeVehicle`, In this case better to write deserialiser at `interface` level.

Implementations of IVehicle interface

```java
// interface which you will be used in @RequestBody
@JsonDeserialize(using = IVehicleDer.class)
interface IVehicle {}
```

```java
@JsonDeserialize(as = CarVehicle.class)
class CarVehicle implements IVehicle {
    @JsonProperty(value = "vehicle_type")
    String vehicleType;
    // getters and setters
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = BikeVehicle.class)
class BikeVehicle implements IVehicle {
    @JsonProperty(value = "vehicle_type")
    String vehicleType;
    // getters and setters
}
```

#### Custom Deserialiser for `interface IVehicle`

```java
class IVehicleDer extends JsonDeserializer<IVehicle> {

    @Override
    public EventI deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
        ObjectNode root = mapper.readTree(p);
        if (root.has("vehicle_type") && root.get("vehicle_type").asText().equals("car")) {
            return mapper.readValue(root.toString(), CarVehicle.class);
        }
        return mapper.readValue(root.toString(), BikeVehicle.class);
    }
}
```

Input JSON

```
{
    "vehicle_type": "bike"
}
```

Above JSON should get deserialize to `BikeVehicle` class.
Do not forget to write `@JsonDeserialize` annotation on top of class.